# update facebook status using flex

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, air

Want to find out if facebook status can be updated through flex or air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link where someone has created a Flex/facebook interface, you should be able to figure all you need to know out from this:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/

A quick search on google can find the answers to many of your questions prior to posting on SO, but I don't mind the occasional softball to boost rep.

Comment: It's got links to the API, following those gives you instructions on how to use the API, what more are you looking for? I think at the very least it answers the question that you asked. It proves you can update status via flex.